# How to fix error "attempt to re-open an already-closed object", when database is not closed by the code?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am developing Android app, which saves data into SQLite, and I have been using this method on other apps, but this one is throwing this exception:

But the method for adding a new row doesn't close the database until all operations are done.

I've searched this problem, and most of answers were "You closed database when there is operation after that", and this is not the case.

This method is working on my other Android Applications, but in this one it's not working.

Add Row, open db and close db code:

```
/**
     * Adds a camera device.
     *
     * @param device    The Device Class whcih will be saved in the database.
     */
    public final void createEntry(final Device device) throws Exception {
        open();

        final ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(devicesColumns[1], AESCryptor.encrypt(device.getDeviceName()));
        values.put(devicesColumns[2], AESCryptor.encrypt(device.getDeviceUrl()));
        values.put(devicesColumns[12], AESCryptor.encrypt(device.getDdnsURL()));
        values.put(devicesColumns[3], AESCryptor.encrypt(device.getUser().getUsername()));
        values.put(devicesColumns[4], AESCryptor.encrypt(device.getUser().getPassword()));
        values.put(devicesColumns[5], AESCryptor.encrypt(new Gson().toJson(device.getCamera())));
        values.put(devicesColumns[6], AESCryptor.encrypt(new Gson().toJson(device.getWlan())));
        values.put(devicesColumns[7], AESCryptor.encrypt(device.getLocalPort()));
        values.put(devicesColumns[8], AESCryptor.encrypt(device.getDDNSPort()));
        values.put(devicesColumns[9], AESCryptor.encrypt(device.getMotioneyeVersion()));
        values.put(devicesColumns[10], AESCryptor.encrypt(device.getMotionVersion()));
        values.put(devicesColumns[11], AESCryptor.encrypt(device.getOsVersion()));


        String insertId = "ID = " + database.insert("DEVICES", null, values);
        if (device.getID() != null) {
            delete_item(device.getID());
            insertId = device.getID();
        }


        final Cursor cursor = database.query("DEVICES", devicesColumns, insertId, null,
                null, null, null);
        cursor.close();
        close();

    }

    public final void open() throws SQLException {
        database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }


    public final void close() {
        dbHelper.close();
    }
```

Logs:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase: /data/user/0/com.developerfromjokela.motioneyeclient/databases/Devices.db
2019-04-23 13:55:32.460 9621-9621/com.developerfromjokela.motioneyeclient W/System.err:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteClosable.acquireReference(SQLiteClosable.java:55)
2019-04-23 13:55:32.460 9621-9621/com.developerfromjokela.motioneyeclient W/System.err:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1234)
2019-04-23 13:55:32.460 9621-9621/com.developerfromjokela.motioneyeclient W/System.err:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1110)
2019-04-23 13:55:32.460 9621-9621/com.developerfromjokela.motioneyeclient W/System.err:     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1278)
2019-04-23 13:55:32.460 9621-9621/com.developerfromjokela.motioneyeclient W/System.err:     at com.developerfromjokela.motioneyeclient.database.Source.createEntry(Source.java:108)
2019-04-23 13:55:32.460 9621-9621/com.developerfromjokela.motioneyeclient W/System.err:     at com.developerfromjokela.motioneyeclient.ui.setup.activities.SetupStartScreen.fillItems(SetupStartScreen.java:359)
2019-04-23 13:55:32.460 9621-9621/com.developerfromjokela.motioneyeclient W/System.err:     at com.developerfromjokela.motioneyeclient.ui.setup.activities.SetupStartScreen.access$500(SetupStartScreen.java:89)
2019-04-23 13:55:32.460 9621-9621/com.developerfromjokela.motioneyeclient W/System.err:     at com.developerfromjokela.motioneyeclient.ui.setup.activities.SetupStartScreen$3$1.run(SetupStartScreen.java:217)
2019-04-23 13:55:32.460 9621-9621/com.developerfromjokela.motioneyeclient W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
2019-04-23 13:55:32.460 9621-9621/com.developerfromjokela.motioneyeclient W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
2019-04-23 13:55:32.460 9621-9621/com.developerfromjokela.motioneyeclient W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
2019-04-23 13:55:32.460 9621-9621/com.developerfromjokela.motioneyeclient W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
2019-04-23 13:55:32.460 9621-9621/com.developerfromjokela.motioneyeclient W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
2019-04-23 13:55:32.460 9621-9621/com.developerfromjokela.motioneyeclient W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
2019-04-23 13:55:32.460 9621-9621/com.developerfromjokela.motioneyeclient W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Comment: can we know what does`open()` and `close()` method do?

Comment: Yes, I've added these @ShadowDroid

Comment: maybe multiple threads are calling the `createEntry()` method at the same time

Comment: @y.allam Only one file is using method createEntry(), so that will not be possible.